# Update ng-cli project to make it progressive web app

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an angular2 app that was crated a while back using ng-cli. Now I realize that ng-cli provides a --mobile flag to create a project with progressive web app features. So how can I update my existing project to do the same with having to re generate the whole project again.

https://github.com/angular/mobile-toolkit/blob/master/guides/cli-setup.md

Comment: the mobile flag is disable now, you're reading outdated document, please follow this tutorial: https://houssein.me/progressive-angular-applications

Comment: and this one https://coryrylan.com/blog/fast-offline-angular-apps-with-service-workers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The --mobile flag has been removed from ng-cli, unfortunately the documentation is pretty outdated. There is some work you need to do to get PWA features working which is very well explained in this recent talk at ng-conf 2017

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ecu1vAO23ZM